# How to remove the country code from mobile in soql

Tags: trigger, soql

In  my user details mobile no contain with the country code but in my referral id does not contain the country code. How can i split the country code from the mobile no.

For example My referral Id was 9876543210 but in my user details it contain like +91 9876543210. if the mobile no having country means then first remove the country and then match with referral id.

I tried the following trigger

```
trigger LeadAssignmentTrigger on Broker__c (before insert,before update) 
{
    List<Broker__c > leadsToUpdate = new List<Broker__c >();

    for (Broker__c broker: Trigger.new)
    {     
      if (broker.Referral_ID__c!= NULL)
      {
          // Find the sales rep for the current zip code
          List<User> zip = [select Id from User
                                   where MobilePhone= :broker.Referral_ID__c ];

          // if you found one
          if (zip.size() > 0) 
          {    
              //assign the lead owner to the zip code owner
              broker.OwnerId = zip[0].Id; 

              leadsToUpdate.add(broker);

          }
       } 

     }

      // update the records

}
```

my user details mobile no contain the country code but in my referral id does not contain the country code. How can i split the country code from the mobile no.

Comment: country code can be `+91` or `+1` etc https://countrycode.org/ .... ?

Comment: now +91 and 91 in my user details. because some user login into salesforce the using mobile verification. thats y it shows +91 and 91. i need the mobile no 10 digit only. Because my org business in india only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The formula will fail if mobile no contains only 10 digits : ex.
>   8888888888 will be stored as (888) 888-8888 and the above formula will return **) 888-8888**.

**Please try the below code it will run in both the cases**

```
trigger LeadAssignmentTrigger on Broker__c (before insert,before update) 
{
    List<Broker__c > leadsToUpdate = new List<Broker__c >();
    for (Broker__c broker: Trigger.new)
    {     
        if (broker.Referral_ID__c!= NULL)
        {
            String str = broker.Referral_ID__c;
            Integer ln = str.Length();
            String likeStr = '%'+str.subString(ln-10, ln-7)+'%'+str.subString(ln-7, ln-4) +'%'+ str.subString(ln-4);

            // Find the sales rep for the current zip code
            List<User> zip = [select Id from User
                                   where MobilePhone Like : likeStr];

            // if you found one
            if (zip.size() > 0) 
            {    
                //assign the lead owner to the zip code owner
                broker.OwnerId = zip[0].Id; 
                leadsToUpdate.add(broker);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a MobilePhoneFormula in `User` object

  ```
  Formula(Text) => RIGHT(MobilePhone, 10)
  ```
- Use that formula in SOQL

  ```
  List<User> zip = [select Id from User
                             where MobilePhoneFormula = :broker.Referral_ID__c ];
  ```

Comment: referral id is contain 10 digit only,but MobilePhone is contain more than 10 digit

Comment: I have updated the answer please verify the latest one

Comment: List<User> zip = [select Id from User
                               where MobilePhone = :broker.Referral_ID__c.right(10) ]; i use this but it does not work.it does not change the owner name

Comment: Try the formula approach, I also realized later the field MobilePhone is more than 10 digit not Referal_Id :)

Comment: thanks.I have one doubt over this some time user login salesforce  the using mobile verification. that time mobile no not saved or wat??? because now i put validation rule

Comment: This should be a workflow with a field update not a trigger.